# If statement works alone in void Start();

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the if statement in PawnHasFallen() only works if its in the start funtion and he calls this logs **Debug.Log($"{pawnName} has fallen", this);** and **Debug.Log("It Aint working mate");** for the pawn that hasnt fall yet. but i doesnt work when its called in the HitBowling script then i only get **Debug.Log("It Aint working mate");**. Why isnt it working when i call it in the other script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject pawnName;

    public Transform tf;

    public Rigidbody rb;


    [SerializeField]
    float eulerAngX;
    [SerializeField]
    float eulerAngY;
    [SerializeField]
    float eulerAngZ;



    public void Start()
    {
        tf = GetComponent<Transform>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        PawnHasFallen();
    }


    public void PawnHasFallen()
    {
        eulerAngX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
        eulerAngY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        eulerAngZ = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
        Debug.Log("Calling this script");

        if (!Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transform.up), 0f))
        {
            Debug.Log($"{pawnName} has fallen", this);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("It Aint working mate");
        }

       
    }

}
```

The script where i call the other script

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HitBowling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Pawn pawn;
    public GameObject pawnPrefab;

    public void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = pawnPrefab;

        pawn = obj.GetComponent<Pawn>();
    }
    
    public IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Big balls");
        //if the ball hits the end of the bowling ally start this 
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Ball")
        {
            Debug.Log("Start de second wait");
            //wait 5 second for starting the fuction
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            Debug.Log("Ended the waiting");
            //this function sees if the pawn has fallen and then gives you points
            pawn.PawnHasFallen();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `pawnPrefab` an actual object in the scene or as the name suggests a prefab asset that was never actually instantiated?

Comment: @derHugo and actual object in the scene

Comment: Are you sure it is the correct object? Is the `Pawn` script attached to the same GameObject as the `HitBowling` script?

Comment: @derHugo there is just one prefab connected so you actually saying i have to make a list of the objects and then it works correctly?

Comment: i was seeing and the prefab thats is connected is not in de scene but at the project files. but i put that prefabe in the scene

Comment: No what I am saying is: You have to put this `HitBowling` script on every individual pawn object .. and then use the according `Pawn` component of the according pawn object ... have you tried to simply use `GetComponent<Pawn>().PawnHasFallen();` instead?

Comment: @derHugo but the HitBowling script is not on the pawn its on a cube what is a trigger collider and when the ball is going trough the cube it has to see if the pawns has fallen. and i tried that yes.

Comment: oh well yes, in that case you should probably use a list of pawns and check on all of them

Comment: oke i will try to do that thanks

Comment: Btw just use `public Pawn[] pawns;` and then `foreach(var pawn in pawns){ pawn.PawnHasFallen(); }` ... no need to use `GameObject` and then `GetComponent` ;) You can then just select all pawns in the scene at once and drag it onto the **name** of the `Pawns` field in the Inspector -> this automatically adds all selected objects to the list

Comment: Thanks @derHugo it works :) you are a great help